# Connecting Ubuntu via a HDMI cable

Tags: connection, hdmi

I'm trying to connect Ubuntu to my TV via a HDMI cable as I do with Windows 7, is this possible and if so how.

Comment: Please provide some more information as to which version of Ubuntu you are using, what kind of graphics card if you have any and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I do it only connecting the cable and switching the notebook display to external monitor (Fn F5 usually). You may have to switch your resolution to something the TV accepts but I think usually HDMI TVs accept a bigger range of resolutions than most monitors.

To have sound through TV speakers, I open sound preferences and select output to the HDMI device that appears when I connect the TV.